# How to only apply a (Wordpress) meta query if it exists

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, posts

I am trying to apply filters in a list of products. Users will use select boxes on the front end and click a button to filter the products.

Every product is it's own post, so I use WP_Query to get the posts. For example, I want all products with the color "red", the material "plastic" and the brand "Bikon". So I use;

```
$color = "red";
$material = "plastic";
$brand = "Bikon";
$query = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type'         => 'products',
    'posts_per_page'    =>  6,
    'post_status'       => 'publish',
    'meta_query'    => array(
        'relation'      => 'AND',
        array(
            'key'       => 'color',
            'value'     => $color,
            'compare'   => '='
        ),
        array(
            'key'       => 'material',
            'value'     => $material,
            'compare'   => '='
        ),
        array(
            'key'       => 'brand',
            'value'     => $brand,
            'compare'   => '='
        )
    )
));
```

And this will work fine if every value get's set. But if only one of the select boxes is used, the other two values will be empty and the query will not return any posts. Is there any way to say "only use this array in the meta query if this value is set"?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can check for definition of variable and add additional filtering if it exists

```
$query_args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'products',
    'posts_per_page' => 6,
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    'meta_query'     => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key'     => 'product_check',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS',
        ),
    ),
);

if(isset($color) && $color) {
    $query_args['meta_query'][] = array('key' => 'color', 'value' => $color, 'compare' => '=');
}

if(isset($material ) && $material ) {
    $query_args['meta_query'][] = array('key' => 'material ', 'value' => $material , 'compare' => '=');
}

if(isset($brand ) && $brand ) {
    $query_args['meta_query'][] = array('key' => 'brand ', 'value' => $brand , 'compare' => '=');
}

$query = new WP_Query($query_args);
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it's because of this piece of code or because of something else, but when I use this method, the code gets stuck in the query.

Comment: Strange, for me it works fine, used this method few times before. Can you share screenshot of full view of code?

Comment: Probably you shoudnt specify meta_query in original query.
So add it only if any of filtering is exists - http://prntscr.com/e1is9a

Comment: Updated answer, check it one more time please.

Comment: Can you comment `meta_key` in original query? will it work, i'm not sure, but probably it can cause conflits. If you need another `meta_key` selector you need enter it to `meta_query` array. Updated answer

Comment: Find a big mistake, we have updating query object, not an args. Try it now please?

Comment: Oh, that's it! Works like a charm now. I really needed to know this, thanks a lot for the help!